# Can I use annotation as a key in a HashMap?

Tags: java, reflection

For example I have a Field that I got through reflection. This field has annotation on it. I use

```
field.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class)
```

to get one. Can I use it as key in hash map? I mean of cause I can, but will this key be unique for the Field?

---

I want `HashMap<CustomAnnotation, Integer>` where Integer value is an index of last used element in a collection that CustomAnnotation has:

```
@CustomAnnotation(values={"ONE", "TWO"})
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use the field as the key (and the annotation as the value)?

Comment: Yes, it will be unique, because you can not specify multiple annotations of the same type on one field.

Comment: @IvanBabanin: But you can specify the same annotation on other fields, and maybe get the same object back for them. Then this cannot be used as a key.

Comment: Maybe you try first? I would suppose that, as long as hashCode() of the annotation is not implemented in some unexpected way, it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Annotation instances as HashMap keys. The [interface defines exactly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#hashCode%28%29) how equals and hashCode should work. In essence they are equal ...

> ... if the specified object represents an annotation that is logically equivalent to this one.

However, I am not sure this is what you want.

In particular, if you have the same `@CustomAnnotation(x=123)` on two different fields, only one of those can go into the map.

Don't you want to key on the Field and get the annotation back?

FWIW, Field (and Class, and Method) can all be used as keys, with "good semantics" (considered equal if refering to the same object).

Comment: In particular, if you have the same @CustomAnnotation(x=123) on two different fields, only one of those can go into the map. -- So if I have in class two annotations on different fields, they will result similar keys, right?

Comment: @ZuzEL they will result similar keys, if they will have equal 'x' fields: @CustomAnnotation(x=123) != @CustomAnnotation(x=124)

Comment: Yes, same ("equal") Annotation object ("key") for two annotations with same content.